# How to make actionsheet go to another view? Xcode, small issue,,,

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am trying to make an `actionsheet` for another button but I get two errors: `"No visible @interface for 'UIstoryboard' declares the selector 'InitiateViewControll:'` and, `"No visible @interface for SWViewController' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:'` I was giving this code so is there any names that I need to name in this to make this code costomized for my code? I am trying to learn i am a noob sorry :( here is the code I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)OpenActionSheetButton:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"There is no going back, are you sure???" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControll:@"storyboardViewName"];
        //Push
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        //Modal
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Please help guys?

Comment: i m not familiar with storyboard. Still i think you can't take UIActionsheet in your xib. So you cannot write IBOutlet with that and IBAction with it's methods.

Comment: HI, i am not using xib. Sorry i dont understand your comment to well. Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code..And SWViewController must have a **Navigation Controller**

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            UIViewController *controller =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardViewIdentifier"];
         //storyboardViewIdentifier is the ViewController identifier you specify in the storyboard

            //PUSH
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
            //Modal
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Man!!!!! Thanks so much!!! What do you mean "Navigation Controller" ? How do i make that work? Should the page that has the actionsheet be part of the "NavigationController" That you drag in from the library or what??? Again thanks! I am learning slowly! LOL ;)

Comment: If you want navigation in your project you need to add one UINaviagtionController and set the initial ViewController as its rootcontroller...

Comment: Ok, so you are saying what I need to do is make the view that has the actionsheet the first page of the two when you drag UINavigationController into your work space from the library right? Im sorry if I am being difficult for you :/ but can you speak in simpler terms for me? Thanks,

Comment: To go from one ViewController to another, you need UINavigationController in your project. Drag and drop  UINavigationController to your storyboard and set your initial ViewController as the UINavigationController's RootController. Now you will be able to call **self.navigationController** and **self presentViewController:** in your code...

Comment: Ok, im getting you now. But do i drag it to the storyboard as in make it so two more views are visible or do i drop it in one of my views? If so do i drop it in the view that has the actionsheet or the one that i want to go to with that actionsheet button?

Comment: You must drop it on the storyboard and set the view (with actionsheet) as root controller. And if my answer was helpful  please accept it as the right answer...

Comment: Yes, you have been very helpful! And i forgot to choose your answer earlier so i just did. I am pretty sure i am annoying you so i am sorry for that but why cant i put my backround, buttons, etc or anything on the NavigationControllers scene? because i wanted to transfer what i have right now on my view to it so i can continue with with the instuctions you gave me up there ^^^

Comment: NavigationController is not a ViewController. You cannot add views and buttons to it...Its purpose it to allow navigation in your application. check [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/) to get a good understanding.

Comment: Alright, so it is impossible to use navigation controller with my project because what i have is basically my main view, where a button takes you to another view where you type in some information then press another button that shows an actionsheet with "continue" and cancel, the continue button takes you to another view or back to the first... a navigation controller would change the style of the app :/

Comment: how do you navigate from main view to another view? i think you must be using navigationcontroller for it...

Comment: I am using storyboard, so all I need to do is right click on a button and drag to the view I want to link

Comment: Check if you have a UINavigationController in your storyboard. If yes, then the code in the  answer will work for you. If not, then add UINavigationController to your storyboard and try it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me:

```
 if(buttonIndex == 0) 
 {
 NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
 Paypal_ViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Paypal_ViewController"];
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```